# sequence of number for a list of tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples that I need to convert to a sequence of numbers. For example, the following list contains a list of arcs (node to node). I need to pick only the nodes to create a route in which only the sequential nodes will be present.

```
arcs= [(1,13), (16,12), (13,16), (12,17)]

route= [1,13,16,12,17]
```

would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you guarantee there is one single route that incorporates all arcs? (e.g. `[(16,12), (13,16), (12,17), (1, 13), (7, 6), (3, 7)]`) If not, what is the expected result? Do you guarantee each node has at most one outgoing and at most one incoming arc? (E.g. `[(16,12), (13,16), (12,17), (1, 13), (13, 17)]`) If not, what is the expected result?

Comment: yes, this incorporates all arcs in a route. One incoming and one outgoing from each node except the start node and last node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem in linear time complexity, you can create a dict that maps each node to the next. Start the route from the node that no other node leads to by taking a set difference between the starting nodes and the destination nodes. Keep appending to the route the next node according to the mapping until the current node no longer has a destination in the mapping:

```
mapping = dict(arcs)
route = [set.difference(*map(set, zip(*arcs))).pop()]
while route[-1] in mapping:
    route.append(mapping[route[-1]])
```

Given your input `arcs`, `route` would become:

```
[1, 13, 16, 12, 17]
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AgedEvilVisitor

Answer (score 2):

You can use `networkx`:

```
# pip install networkx
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_edgelist(arcs)
routes = list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, arcs[0][0], arcs[-1][1]))
print(routes)

Output:
[[1, 13, 16, 12, 17]]
```

Comment from @Amadan:

> For a bit more robustness, you can find the route endpoints like this, instead of relying on them being in a particular position in `arcs` list

```
start, end = [node for node, degree in G.degree if degree == 1]
routes = list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, start, end))
```

Comment: For a bit more robustness, you can find the route endpoints like this, instead of relying on them being in a particular position in `arcs` list: `start, end = [node for node, degree in G.degree if degree == 1]`. Still, this is one of only two answers that understood the question.

Comment: @Amadan. Thanks for your comment. I updated my answer according your comment and give you the credits. Feel free to edit my answer if something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps,

```
arcs= [(1,13), (16,12), (13,16), (12,17)]
route=[]
for x in arcs:
    for y in x:
        if y not in route:
            route.append(y)
print (route)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 13, 16, 12, 17]
```

**PS:** If this is not the expected output please modify your question with code.

Answer (score -1):

just do a simple iteration over iteration

for that you can have a code like this

```
arcs = [(1,13), (16,12), (13,16), (12,17)]

route = []

    
for i in arcs:
  for j in i:
    if j not in route:
        rout.append(j)
```